# Git hooks forcing message format

Tags: git, devops, githooks

I want to change the way our team is committing messages to github.
I want to be able to use the pre commit git hooks but i couldn't find a way except the local folder .git/hooks/exutable_hook_file.

Basically i need to force all of the team for a specific message format, before pushing to origin, without asking them to make any manual work on their side.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz i know gitlab has this function and many more but at the moment it's an overkill for us to move to gitlab just for hooks. i really find it hard to believe there is no option to automatically enable commit message hooks on git. it's really frustrating. i wish someone will come with an idea or a solution

Comment: Well it can be a little bit of pain depending on size of organization.